# How can I use sqlplus in a csh script

Tags: sqlplus, csh

I need to run a series of sqlplus commands in a csh script and save the text output to a variable. This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
#!/bin/csh

set results = `sqlplus -s uname/password << END\
select column from table;\
END`

echo "Exited sqlplus"

exit 0
```

But my output reads

```
END: Command not found
Missing }.
```

The current solution was taken from this link, but it isn't working for me.

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/107175-csh-script-can-i-set-variable-result-sqlplus-select-query.html

Anybody know how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While typing the question I found a solution to my own problem. Posting because there doesn't seem to be a similar question suggested by StackOverflow

The solution is to have the gravemarks only encompass the sqlplus command like so

```
#!/bin/csh

set results = `sqlplus -s uname/password` << END
select column from table;
END

echo "Exited sqlplus"

exit 0
```

And now I get my output of `COLUMN----RES1 RES2 RES3`

Comment: Dude who pointed this up 8 years later? Use a different shell lol